# Find_by_id in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have products that can be a **part** of an **assembly**. I only had one assembly, which I called a **bundle**.

Originally, given that a **product** had any **parts**, I included an additional option

If I use

```
<% if @product.parts.any?(&:in_stock?) %>
 HERE I SHOW OPTION FORM
<% end %>
```

This works, and displays my option. However now I have another option I'd like to show.

I need to show options to corresponding IDs. It seems that my original product part has an ID of 'bundle', so I tried:

```
<% if @product.parts.find_by_id('bundle') %>
```

However my option doesn't load. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? I don't get an error, it's just not finding that id.

Rails 4 & Spree 2.1+

Comment: is 'bundle' int? try find_by_id(params[:part_id])

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using a gem like friendly_id, I don't think the id of your parts are going to be 'bundle'. Usually they're an autoincremented integer. Are you 100% sure that that's the id? I would suggest looking at rails built in find methods [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by). It looks like you might want find_by_name.

Answer (score 0):

My schema revealed that what I was looking for was an integer:

```
    t.integer "part_id"
```

That particular product part was loading DB:

```
Spree::AssembliesPart Load  SELECT "spree_assemblies_parts".* FROM "spree_assemblies_parts" WHERE "spree_assemblies_parts"."assembly_id" = 4 AND "spree_assemblies_parts"."part_id" = 6 LIMIT 1
```

I then used the part_id that was loaded, which in my case was 6.

This find_by method then worked:

```
    <% if @product.parts.find_by_id('6') %>
```